# Sencha Touch on Internet Explorer with Google Chrome Frame plugin

Tags: internet-explorer, webkit, sencha-touch, google-chrome-frame

I'd like to develop with Sencha Touch but I have to deal with Internet Explorer.
As far as I know, ST is supported only by webkit-based browsers, so IE is not an option.

But what about running a Sencha Touch project inside Internet Explorer (7) with the Google Frame plugin?

http://www.google.com/chromeframe

Has anybody ever tried this combination? It could work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can** use the chrome frame extension to develop Sencha Touch apps in Internet Explorer.

After you install the plugin, you need to add a registry entry to allow the forced use of the extension via prefixing the URL.

Follow the instructions here:
http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started#TOC-Testing-Your-Sites

"You must use both the gcf: and http: prefixes. To enable this testing-only feature, open regedit.exe and add a DWORD value AllowUnsafeURLs=1 under HKCU\Software\Google\ChromeFrame.  By default only gcf:about:blank and gcf:about:version are allowed."

Once you edit the registry, you can call something like this in the URL: 
gcf:C:\Projects\SenchaProject\index.html

The dev tools for IE don't seem to work when sites are displayed in the chrome frame, so development might be tricky unless you can find some other extension which plays nice.